# Parsing words inside of Lex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex

I'm new to lex (or flex) and I have a probably simple question. I want to recognize when a user types in "show " and retrieve the name and store it as a variable. Can I do this with some lex keywords or something? Or would just passing it to a method and parsing at the space be easiest? 
side note:  could include spaces in it

Answer (score 1):

Flex is a tool that is used to create a lexical analyzer. The role of the lexical analyzer, be it generated by Flex or otherwise, is to split the input into tokens. That is, it takes the input stream of characters, **s-h-o-w-space**, and recognizes that it starts with the token **show**.

Doing other things, such as storing variable names and values, is better done elsewhere.